# Flash Builder (Mobile) - Dynamic Web Service URL

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, mobile, flash-builder, flex4.6

For my Flash Builder 4.6 Project I have a http service defined which looks at a url from our website.

What I'd like to be able to do though is to change the web service url on the fly within the app. i.e. using the existing url as default but having an admin/settings screen to change where the web service points (either stored in our sqlite database or in local memory).

This would be so that we could allow our customers to host their own version of the website/database but still be able to use/download the app through the app stores.

Has anyone had any experience with doing this?

EDIT: Adding some more details after the comments below.

When I created the HTTP Service through the FlashBuilder wizard it creates two web service classes a super class and a sub class which inherits from the super class. All of the code that the wizard populates goes into the super class.

I can assume that the code I need to put in would be in the sub class. But I do not know which function I'd put it in or how.

Below is a sample of the Super's constructor:

```
// initialize service control
    _serviceControl = new mx.rpc.http.HTTPMultiService("websitehere");
     var operations:Array = new Array();
     var operation:mx.rpc.http.Operation;
     var argsArray:Array;

     operation = new mx.rpc.http.Operation(null, "loginRequest");
     operation.url = "login.php";
     operation.method = "GET";
     argsArray = new Array("un","pw");
     operation.argumentNames = argsArray;         
     operation.serializationFilter = serializer0;
     operation.properties = new Object();
     operation.properties["xPath"] = "/";
     operation.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     operation.resultType = valueObjects.Data;
     operations.push(operation);
_serviceControl.operationList = operations;
```

I'm not sure what property of the _serviceControl variable I would need to alter.

Also when I search for my website in my code it brings back a .fml file inside a .model directory which seems to get auto refreshed if I change the service url through the wizard. Would this not cause an issue?

I then have the challenge of accessing the user defined url. Within the app we use an sqlite database to store data but I think it would probably be better to use a 'SharedObject' which we also use to know what account they are logged into. How reliable is this? I assume I would be able to access this via the Service?

Though the awkward thing is that we were planning to have this configurable on a settings screen that would have been accessed after logging in. But to log in it would already need to know which server to point to.

Comment: What is your specific issue? What you describe is easily achievable, but your question is too broad.

Comment: I've created dynamic / changeable URLs from my app in any number of ways.  Tell us what you've trued and why it isn't working and perhaps we can help more explicitly.

Comment: Apologies about that, I've edited the original question with some more details and a code sample of what the FlashBuilder wizard generated alongside some more specific questions on whether using a SharedObject is the right way to go and how I would alter the sub class of the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cghrmauritius' solution didn't quite work for me, I am posting up the final solution that did work in my situation.

```
public function subConstructor()
{
    super();
    _serviceControl.baseURL = "http://url1";
}
```

Obviously for my final solution I need to implement the shareobject as well but overriding the url was my main priority.

Answer (score 1):

if im reading your question correctly then your main ambition is to dynamically change the url for the services based on a user defined variable.

This is very easy to accomplish and even easier to accomplish if you are using parsley / spicelib.

a few points

1. dont change the code in the super file, this will get overwritten whenever the service gets refreshed. change everything in its generated sub-Class.
2. Shared Objects are very good for small quantities of data but should never be used for massive datasets i.e storing a big arraycollection.

Anyway here is how i achieve this.

In the SubClass you can change the constructor function.

Here is how i change my urls based on a config variable but you can just as easily use a SharedObject instead.

```
public function SubClassConstructor(){
    if(CONFIG::DOMAIN_IDENT == "development" || CONFIG::DOMAIN_IDENT == "dev" || CONFIG::DOMAIN_IDENT == "d"){
        _serviceControl.endpoint = "http://yoururl1";
    }
    else if(CONFIG::DOMAIN_IDENT == "production" || CONFIG::DOMAIN_IDENT == "prod" || CONFIG::DOMAIN_IDENT == "p"){
        _serviceControl.endpoint = "http://yoururl2";
    }

}
```

Of course this isn't exactly what your looking for but its a working solution, of course you can use Bindings to a Global ApplicationModel or direct reference to the SharedObject i guess you already know how to use the SharedObject.

Ask if you need any further help or guidance.

Comment: I've given your answer an up-vote as you definitely pointed me in the right direction though for me endpoint was not defined. So I've posted up my final code as the answer. Instead I had to use a property called baseUrl which seemed to work as intended.

I've not put the shared-object in but that won't be the hard part. I just didn't know how to override the url programmatically. I've added an extra answer with the final code that I used.